# Gson how to deserialize when the concrete implementation type is unkown

Tags: java, json, gson

Let's say I've go an interface `Request` with an `void handle();` method (pretty much like a command pattern). I've got several implementations of this interface. My application will receive serailized `Request` objects, but as far as I am concerned I have to tell the gson deserializer a concrete class, so `ConcreteRequest` (which implements `Request`) for example. The JSON for all of them looks exactly the same, so how do I decide which class I have to cast it to? Is there any specific way to do this automatically or any workaround?

Comment: There is none ( if the layout is the same). But you can add a String field to the json file which determines the type you are gonna parse to.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Then I'd have to read this one field before I actually deserialize the json, right? Is this generally even the right approach that I'm taking?

Comment: There is no 'correct' and 'incorrect' code in my opinion. It doesnt sound overly complicated, and if it works nobody will complain :p. Anyway, yes you'll need to read that field first. But since you use the Gson library, you need to create some sort of deserializer for the request object nontheless. So reading that field first shouldnt be that big of a problem.

Comment: If you go the route of using a String field to indicate the type, and you receive a list of objects, this might be helpful: https://futurestud.io/blog/how-to-deserialize-a-list-of-polymorphic-objects-with-gson

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a really elegant solution.